# How to debug missing fields and elements in Odoo views (some disappeared after an upgrade)

Tags: xml, debugging, odoo

I upgraded an Odoo v9 20151008 to v9c 20151215. Changing the codebase went smooth and my Apps worked like before. But after the app upgrades (via the `Upgrade` button) I am missing the Product column (field `product_id`) and the top bare to send sale orders as emails in the `sale.order.form`. This makes it impossible to save sale orders.

Now in the developer modus I can view and edit the form's XML as well as a bunch of other stuff. But unfortunately the obvious thought, which was that the XML got changed on the upgrade, was wrong. The XML of the upgraded and misfunctional `sale.order.form` in my development environment matches the XML of the same form in my non upgraded and working environment (and the top bar as well as the `product_id` field is existent in both).

The odoo log also shows no signs of errors.
What would be the next and best way to debug such a thing (preferable with but if not useful also without the odoo debugging tools)?